# Show count concatenated to labels using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to construct pie chart, is there any way to concatenate the Count to the label (Displaying numbers and percentages in a pie chart legend)?

```js
createChart : function() {
    debugger;
    var chartData = [60, 90, 120, 150];
    var chartLabels = ['apples','bananas','oranges','pears'];
    var chartCanvas = component.find("chart").getElement();

    var chart = new Chart(chartCanvas, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: chartLabels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "test",
                        data: chartData,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#f43004",
                            "#decf3f",
                            "#FFA500"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                cutoutPercentage: 1,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position:'right',
                    fullWidth:false,
                    reverse:true,
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000',
                        fontSize:10,
                        fontFamily:"Arial, sans-serif SANS_SERIF"
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: 70,
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am trying to construct chart like this:

[image]

Please provide any suggestions or pointers to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [html-legends](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) feature so you can customize the Chart.js legend:

```
legendCallback : function (chart) {
    var text = [];
    text.push('<ul class="0-legend">');
    var ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
    var sum = ds.data.reduce(function add(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < ds.data.length; i++) {
        text.push('<li>');
        var perc = Math.round(100 * ds.data[i] / sum, 0);
        text.push('<span style="background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor[i] + '">' + '</span>' + chart.data.labels[i] + ' (' + ds.data[i] + ') (' + perc + '%)');
        text.push('</li>');
    }
    text.push('</ul>');
    return text.join("");
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/b5hdn9gw/

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var chartData = [60, 90, 120, 150];
var chartLabels = ['apples','bananas','oranges','pears'];

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#f43004",
        "#decf3f",
        "#FFA500",
        "#9b59b6",
      ],
      data: chartData
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
      var text = [];
      text.push('<ul class="0-legend">');
      var ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
      var sum = ds.data.reduce(function add(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
      for (var i=0; i<ds.data.length; i++) {
        text.push('<li>');
        var perc = Math.round(100*ds.data[i]/sum,0);
        text.push('<span style="background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor[i] + '">' + '</span>' + chart.data.labels[i] + ' ('+ds.data[i]+') ('+perc+'%)');
        text.push('</li>');
      }
      text.push('</ul>');
      return text.join("");
    }
  }
});

var myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legend");
// generate HTML legend
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
// bind onClick event to all LI-tags of the legend
var legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);
}

function legendClickCallback(event) {
  event = event || window.event;

  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while (target.nodeName !== 'LI') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  var parent = target.parentElement;
  var chartId = parseInt(parent.classList[0].split("-")[0], 10);
  var chart = Chart.instances[chartId];
  var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(target);
  var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
  console.log(index);
 var item = meta.data[index];

  if (item.hidden === null || item.hidden === false) {
    item.hidden = true;
    target.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    target.classList.remove('hidden');
    item.hidden = null;
  }
  chart.update();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

.container { 
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#chart {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

#legend {
  float: right;
}

[class$="-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
}

[class$="-legend"] li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class$="-legend"] li.hidden {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

[class$="-legend"] li span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Chart.js — Pie Chart Demo Percent</h2>
  <div>
      <div id="chart"><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
      <div id="legend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var chartData = [60, 90, 120, 150];
var chartLabels = ['apples','bananas','oranges','pears'];

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#f43004",
        "#decf3f",
        "#FFA500",
        "#9b59b6",
      ],
      data: chartData
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
      var text = [];
      text.push('<ul class="0-legend">');
      var ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
      var sum = ds.data.reduce(function add(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
      for (var i=0; i<ds.data.length; i++) {
        text.push('<li>');
        var perc = Math.round(100*ds.data[i]/sum,0);
        text.push('<span style="background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor[i] + '">' + '</span>' + chart.data.labels[i] + ' ('+ds.data[i]+') ('+perc+'%)');
        text.push('</li>');
      }
      text.push('</ul>');
      return text.join("");
    }
  }
});

var myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legend");
// generate HTML legend
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
// bind onClick event to all LI-tags of the legend
var legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);
}

function legendClickCallback(event) {
  event = event || window.event;

  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while (target.nodeName !== 'LI') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  var parent = target.parentElement;
  var chartId = parseInt(parent.classList[0].split("-")[0], 10);
  var chart = Chart.instances[chartId];
  var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(target);
  var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
  console.log(index);
    var item = meta.data[index];

  if (item.hidden === null || item.hidden === false) {
    item.hidden = true;
    target.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    target.classList.remove('hidden');
    item.hidden = null;
  }
  chart.update();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

.container { 
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#chart {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

#legend {
  float: right;
}

[class$="-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
}

[class$="-legend"] li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class$="-legend"] li.hidden {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

[class$="-legend"] li span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Chart.js — Pie Chart Demo Percent</h2>
  <div>
      <div id="chart"><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
      <div id="legend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32131966)